# return value from db is null

Tags: c#

I am not sure why I am getting this error. If the confirmedAcceptance value is null or empty, it will be false and return zero, Otherwise, it should return the returned value from the DB. If this is right, why I am getting the error below?

```
int confirmedAcceptance = 0;
confirmedAcceptance = string.IsNullOrEmpty((dr["confirmedAcceptance"].ToString()) ? 0 : int.Parse(dr["confirmedAcceptance"].ToString());
```

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
> correct format.

Comment: What kind of column was `confirmedAcceptance` on the database?

Answer (score 0):

`int.Parse()` is not a generic conversion function. It expects – nay, requires – a string value for the input. But if the `confirmedAcceptance` column in the database is a number type like `int` rather than a textual type like `nvarchcar`, you won't have a string value here.

Instead, do a direct check for null and simple cast to `int`, like this:

```
int confirmedAcceptance = DBNull.Value.Equals(dr["confirmedAcceptance"]) ? 0 : (int)dr["confirmedAcceptance"];
```

I might also keep a shortcut extension method like this:

```
public static int GetIntOrDefault(this IDataRecord source, string FieldName, int defaultValue = 0)
{
    return DBNull.Value.Equals(source[FieldName]) ? defaultValue: (int)(source[FieldName]);
}
```

And then you can use this throughout your program for int fields in a datareader like this:

```
int confirmedAcceptance = dr.GetIntOrDefault("confirmedAcceptance");
```

or when you want, say, a `1` instead of a `0`:

```
int confirmedAcceptance = dr.GetIntOrDefault("confirmedAcceptance", 1);
```

Then have similar methods for strings, dates, doubles, decimals, and binary data (the basic types of SQL column), along with possibly another set of extensions for `DataRow` (I dream of world where `DataRow` also implements the `IDataRecord` interface).